# React useEffect only called once per app instance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a project which has screens designed using functional components and hooks. I came across some code which is not working as per my understanding. I know useEffect if has an empty array as dependency, it should be called once per component lifecycle but its not working.

```
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSomeState((prevState) => !prevState);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect');
    console.log(someState);
  }, [someState]);
```

Outuput:

```
[Thu Nov 11 2021 11:52:58.384]  LOG      useEffect
[Thu Nov 11 2021 11:52:58.385]  LOG      false
[Thu Nov 11 2021 11:52:58.404]  LOG      useEffect
[Thu Nov 11 2021 11:52:58.405]  LOG      true
```

**This only prints useEffect in console once. Now when I go back and come to this screen, it doesnt print anything but as per my understanding it should print. So somehow between screen navigation useState is being persisted or screen instance.**

Libs:

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

Screen is part of Drawer navigator

Comment: My guess is you are not unmounting the component when navigating. If you unmount and then mount the component again, the whole cycle happens again.

Comment: @SobhanJahanmard sir I have never written code to unmount component manually, can you show me how to do it please

Comment: @SobhanJahanmard I am simply navigating back to previous screen using navigation.goBack() which unmounts the screen it self

Answer (score 0):

Since I have little information about your code, I will just use a raw setup that shows you the way.

```
export default const componentA = ()=>{
const [toBeOrNotToBe,setToBeOrNotToBe]=useState(true)
const unmounter= ()=>{
    setToBeOrNotToBe(false)
}
useMemo(()=> {
  setTimeout(() =>setToBeOrNotToBe(true), 1000);
} ,[toBeOrNotToBe])
return {
    {toBeOrNotToBe && <ComponentB mounter={mounter}/>}
}

}
```

in ComponentB define a button that triggers `props.mounter()`. So when you clcik on the button your ComponentB gets unmounted and then gets mounted again because of the useMemo hook.